# How do I solve this differential equation for the maximum value of $y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y''+2y'+2y=0$$ with initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=5$. Find the maximum value of $y$ over $0 \leq x < \infty$.

I have tried to solve for $y$ and have gotten stuck at the point when I am trying to find the maximum value of $y$.

Comment: Well, what did you find $y$ to be?

Answer (score 1):

First note that the characteristic equation is: $t^2+2t+2=0$. So, the roots of it are $-1\pm i$. Hence the general solution is $y(x)= c_1 e^{-x}\sin x + c_2 e^{-x}\cos x$. By initial conditions, we have $c_2=0$ and $c_1=5$. Therefore the solution of the differential equation is $y(x)=5e^{-x}\sin x$.

finding the maximum value of $y(x)$:
Note that
$$y^\prime (x) = -5e^{-x}\sin x +5e^{-x}\cos x=0.$$ then, $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. So, the maximum value of $y(x)$ is $5 \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}e^{-\dfrac{\pi}{4}} $.